# how to find the memory usage of ArrayList in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, collections

suppose I have an ArrayList of 10k employee objects.

how do i find  **total memory size of ArrayList?**

how do i calculate the usage of ArrayList?

Comment: I suppose a decent profiler should be able to tell you this.

Comment: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/

Comment: in terms of coding,is there any way to find the memory size?

Comment: Keep in mind that the space allocated for the ArrayList only contains the pointers to the objects not the objects themselves.

Comment: Do you know what the initial capacity was? Because then you can just divide by that and find the next power of 1.5 and that should give you a good approximation

Comment: Do you want the amount of memory allocated for the array of references inside ArrayList or the amount of memory taken up by the 10k objects on the heap?

Comment: @bhspencer it is like how much amount of memory it is holding for 10k objects